# mod_rewrite hide file extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt .php
```

my .htaccess uses the main "files.php" for all requests.
in my files.php i have some code in it that includes hrefs which looks like this:

`/people/john` --> when a person clicks on this, it should go to: `people.php?q=john`
however, my .htaccess is not redirecting when person clicks on this `/people/john`.
btw, the url should always say `/people/john` NOT `people.php?q=john` even though that is what is happening behind the scenes.

Just wanted to say, i have

```
/city/newyork --> city.php?q=newyork
/country/australia --> country.php?q=australia
```

I have been struggling and searching here to find exactly, but still no luck. i appreciate all the responses.

Comment: You're not alone, mod_rewrite rules can be confusing. I would love to see the solution to this...

Comment: We need to see the code you're talking about; we can't help just from knowing that it doesn't work.

Comment: G-Nuggets, my code is included above. all the url is handled in the "files.php" so files.php is like the main index or directory where everything gets handled. so it contain stuff like this: /city/newyork, etc. and on the url it looks like this /city/newyork, however behind the scene this is actually the scripts that renders: city.php?q=newyork. hth.

Comment: I think what @G-Nugget (and the rest of us) would like to see is a sample href - the whole tag. Please include 2 or 3 different ones that demonstrate the url that is in the href.

Comment: the files.php code itself is straight forward, basically i am querying the db and inserting user information to the href. when i force it with country.php?q=australia, code works smooth, the problem is when i try to click on the href link on my browser, and nothing happens, it basically stays on the screen, and flicker. thanks for your comments.

Comment: If the script **files.php** is handling everything, including the redirection. **What do you need the rewrite code for?** What do you mean "...when i try to click on the *href link* on my browser.."? What **href** link in your browser, they  exist only in files, besides, you just said "*..files.php is like the main index or directory where everything gets handled..*"? I don't think you need any .htaccess rewrite code to solve the problem, if any, in your question. And, in fact, I don't think there is any problem with the current code in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. see on a web browser, you can click on a link, well that link looks like this "mywebsite.com/city/newyork" when you mouseover it. however, this "mywebsite.com/city/newyork" is being written to appear like this format in my files.php. so when i click on this ""mywebsite.com/city/newyork"", nothing happens, so clearly, my .htaccess is not working! hth.

Comment: Your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1` always redirects except when the directory or the file exist, because the regex matches everything. Can't be an error there, that's my point. Add flags [R,L] so you can **see** the substitution URL. If you see `mywebsite.com/files.php?q=city/newyork` for a request like `mywebsite.com/city/newyork`, the problem is with the script (files.php) or with the Options, not with the rule. Options should be `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`, by the way.

Comment: Faa, pls look at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your examples, you've got url's like this:

```
/city/newyork, where city is the php file to call with parameter newyork
```

If that's what you want, try this:
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine on

```
# Rewrite /city/newyork to city.php?q=newyork
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /$1.php?q=$2 [L]

# Rewrite all urls without a second / to files.php?q=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /files.php?q=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .txt .php
```

Comment: Thanks but it is till not working, I am using cpanel, do you think other than .htaccess is there anything else I should be looking for? as in the apache virtual host or something? maybe something wasn't set up properly?

Comment: Did you get an infinitive loop? I think it was missing a [L] at the end of the RewriteRule lines.

Comment: oh God your solution is so close, ok so the folder structure is working, however when i only have www.mywebsite.com/newyork, it is changing it to www.mywebsite.com/newyork.php, it should rather be www.mywebsite.com/myfiles.php?q=newyork, we need to fix the rewrite condition, but your close with an answer!!! help me:) don't forget the url should always read: www.mywebsite.com/newyork

Comment: is there a way to say if else statement in mod rewrite? because your answer works for the /city/newyork, however its breaking if i only have /newyork/

Comment: this was the right answer all along, i had to change $_REQUEST['q'] to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and it woked as a charm, it took me several days, THANK U!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make it dynamic? I mean, `/$anything1/$anything2` will be remapped into `/$anything1.php?=$anything2`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1.php?q=%2
```

Or try this if the code above doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1.php?q=%2 [P]
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working, I am using cpanel, do you think other than .htaccess is there anything else I should be looking for? as in the apache virtual host or something? maybe something wasn't set up properly?

Comment: What's happening? Do you really want to rewrite them or to redirect? According to your question, your `RewriteEngine` is workin'. Anyway, you can check my updates above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use with CodeIgniter (supports very deep a/b/c/d/e/f/g)

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ files.php?/$1 [L]
```

Essentially line by line it says
- switch rewrite engine on
- use the web_root (so it may not be / for you if you are in a sub-folder)
- if the url is not an existing file
- and the url is not an existing dir
- map the argument to files.php

Just realized you are using Files.php... strange, should just call it index for consistency if it is what everything should route through, or make an index that routes folder/files/* through to index.php?tab=files&...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but it is till not working, I am using cpanel, do you think other than .htaccess is there anything else I should be looking for? as in the apache virtual host or something? maybe something wasn't set up properly?

Answer (score 0):

Faa, I did what you said, and below is my server variables, i think the correct variables should be the one that says "should be this:" below.

```
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(17) "q=city/newyork"
  ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(17) "q=city/newyork"
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(16) "/city/newyork"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(16) "/city/newyork"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(30) "/home/mywebsite/myfiles.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(14) "/myfiles.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(14) "/myfiles.php"
  ["argv"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "q=city/newyork"
  }




should be this:
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(16) "q=newyork"
  ["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(16) "q=newyork"
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(25) "/city/newyork"
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(25) "/city/newyork"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(30) "/home/mywebsite/city.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(14) "/city.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(14) "/city.php"
  ["argv"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "q=newyork"
  }
```

Comment: Jeroen's solution is close to pick an answer. so basically his code is working, however, the server is is doing this www.mywebsite.com/newyork.php where as it should be www.mywebsite.com/myfiles.php?q=newyork the url should also appear neat and cool like this www.mywebsite.com/newyork

Comment: The "REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING" is `"q=city/newyork"`, so the **REDIRECTION IS WORKING**. If you want only `"q=newyork"`, don 't enter *city/newyork*, enter only */newyork* in the browser's bar or link. It's easy, the rule passes the whole URI-path as that is what you told it to do with the (.*) group. To exclude `city` from the group, change the rule to `RewriteRule ^city/(.*) /myfiles.php?q=$1 [R,L]`

Comment: But, again, the problem is NOT with the rules. The problem is with the PHP code as I said several times. Is the code in the script that should be able to **explode** or separate the GET query string into the corresponding parameters. It is important to have the whole URI-path like now, so don't change the rule, change the code. There are hundreds of examples on how to do what you need, so delete your answers here, that answer nothing, and post another question asking for the code.

Comment: Faa, what i posted is exact same code from two different server doing the same thing, however, the other server is the one where the problem. the rules and code are photocopied but shared on two different servers, do u think thats the problem?

Comment: Sure, it could be if both URL structures are not identical. If they are not, you should modify the code in the other server accordingly.

Comment: Jeroens rule worked except /newyork now has .php extension with it. i will see if i can use that. it is so strange, i have the same code running for different countries on different servers and i am stumbling on this one, which makes me want to pull my hair out. thanks for your help Faa.